# Align navbar dropdown items next

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align my dropdown-items made by Bootstrap 4 next to eachother like this:

[image]

Where Item 1 and 2 are dropdown items when hovering over the first Test item.

I have tried using `float: left` in CSS but that did not work unfortunately.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

But right now they are underneath eachother like this:

[image]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" id="NavbarToggler">Welkom</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="NavbarToggler">
                    <a class="dropdown-item mt-2" href="info">Informatie Stedenband</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="geschiedenis">Geschiedenis Stedenband</a>
                </div>
            </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align dropdown items side by side, Use this code

```
.dropdown-menu a{
  display:inline;
  padding:5px;
}
```

OR

if you want to align dropdown items in line by line, Use this code

```
.dropdown-menu a{
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work with both pieces of code, the items are still underneath one another.

Answer (score 0):

Use **d-inline-block** and **w-auto** classes with dropdown-item

Comment: I added this and didn't work, still aligning under one another.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet. Where you use this.